# Visual Studio Code output encoding incorrect for golang

Tags: visual-studio-code

When running golang tests in Visual Studio Code, I get the following output:

[visual-studio-code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXd3Y.jpg)

I'm running Windows 10 with US English as my locale. Does anyone have any ideas?

I've tried changing fonts in VSCode.

Comment: Does it work in cmd.exe? Seems like vscode doesn't support ansi escape sequences.

Comment: Can you please explain what your problem is?

Comment: Same result in cmd.exe, except instead of boxes I'm getting boxes with question marks... so that means it must be a Windows system issue, right?

Comment: @Vakore the problem is around encoding and lack of color and correct characters compared to a regular bash output. Makes it really hard to read the results.